# How to use STR_TO_DATE function in Rails query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 4 + Mysql

This is one query in mysql working fine.

```
select * from `schedules` 
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') >= TIME(NOW()) and travel_date ='2014-06-09' and origin_id ='134' and destination_id ='251' and operator_id not in (SELECT id FROM `operators` WHERE (status != 'Active')) and status ='Active' and available_seats > 0)
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p');
```

This query i want to write in Rails. how to give this one `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p')'; in rails 4 Any suggestion/Hint...

Comment: What is **`STR_TO_DATE`**?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/